# Laravel: stored image from the database doesn't show up

Tags: php, html, laravel, ubuntu, content-management-system

I am using Laravel, and while displaying the stored image from the database the image doesn't show up:

```
$post -> image has posts/1lSBv7Ana8Lonj9Au37IrujjnnEaYgzNWyamch33.jpeg as image location, still image doesn't show up.
```

index.blade.php

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{$post->image}}" width="60px" height="60px" alt="image">
                </td>
                <td>{{$post->title}} </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

and PostsController as

```
public function index()
{
    return \view('posts.index')->with('posts', Post::all());
}
```

Comment: use  src="{{asset($post->image)}}"

Comment: give  folder path where images are store

Answer (score 0):

If you're using local or public disk storage you may use

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $post->image) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Laravel Documentation
You can use `asset()` helper function to get the image

> **asset()** The asset function generates a URL for an asset using the
>   current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS)

```
<img src="asset({{$post->image}})" width="60px" height="60px" alt="image">
```

Reference:

[Laravel -> Helpers -> Method asset](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-asset)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to store the images in the public directory (if not the browser can't access them)

Then it depends what $post->image actually is. If it is a path relative to public you can do this:

```
<img src="{{ asset($post->image) }}" />
```

or this

```
{{ HTML::image($post->image, '', array('class' => 'image')); }}
```

Comment: you have to prepend that: ```<img src="{{ asset('img/' . $post->image) }}" />```

Answer (score 0):

make a command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

then wrap your image name with asset() function

```
<img src="{{asset($post->image)}}" width="60px" height="60px" alt="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, but i got rid of it by,

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and in index page

```
<img src="{{asset("storage/$post->image")}}" width="60px" height="60px" alt="image">
```